My custom meta box with textarea field not saved
I created a custom meta box for my custom post type with address, phone, and map but only the map field type textarea not saved.
My code here:
// Add meta box
function vn_store_add_meta_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'vn_store_info', // ID
    'Store Details', // Title
    'vn_store_meta_box_callback', // Callback
    'vn_store', // Post type
    'normal', // Context
    'high' // Priority
);}add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'vn_store_add_meta_box');

// Display meta box
function vn_store_meta_box_callback($post) {
// Add a nonce field for security
wp_nonce_field('vn_store_save_meta_box_data', 'vn_store_meta_box_nonce');

// Retrieve existing values from the database
$store_map = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_vn_store_map', true);
$store_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_vn_store_address', true);
$store_phone = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_vn_store_phone', true);

// Display the form fields
echo '<div id="vn_store_meta_box">';

echo '<label for="vn_store_address">Store Address: </label>';
echo '<input type="text" id="vn_store_address" name="vn_store_address" value="' . esc_attr($store_address) . '" size="25" />';

echo '<label for="vn_store_phone">Store Phone Number: </label>';
echo '<input type="text" id="vn_store_phone" name="vn_store_phone" value="' . esc_attr($store_phone) . '" size="25" />';

echo '<label for="vn_store_map">Store Map: </label>';
echo '<textarea id="vn_store_map" name="vn_store_map" rows="5" cols="50">' . esc_textarea($store_map) . '</textarea>';
echo '<p>Get store map from <a href="https://www.google.com/maps" target="_blank">Google Map</a></p>';
echo '</div>';}

// Save meta box
function vn_store_save_meta_box_data($post_id) {
// Check if our nonce is set
if (!isset($_POST['vn_store_meta_box_nonce'])) {
    return;
}

// Verify that the nonce is valid
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['vn_store_meta_box_nonce'], 'vn_store_save_meta_box_data')) {
    return;
}

// If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return;
}

// Check the user's permissions
if (isset($_POST['post_type']) && 'vn_store' == $_POST['post_type']) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
        return;
    }
} else {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return;
    }
}

// Sanitize and save user inputs
if (isset($_POST['vn_store_map'])) {
    $store_map = sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['vn_store_map']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_vn_store_map', $store_map);
}

if (isset($_POST['vn_store_address'])) {
    $store_address = sanitize_text_field($_POST['vn_store_address']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_vn_store_address', $store_address);
}

if (isset($_POST['vn_store_phone'])) {
    $store_phone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['vn_store_phone']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_vn_store_phone', $store_phone);
}}add_action('save_post', 'vn_store_save_meta_box_data');


sanitize_textarea_field() will be stripping out the GMaps <iframe> element. Sanitize it with wp_kses( $store_map, $allowed ) instead, where $allowed is an array in the following format:
$allowed = array(
    'iframe' => array(
        'width' => array(),
        'height' => array(),
        'style' => array(),
        'loading' => array(),
        'allowfullscreen' => array(),
        'referrerpolicy' => array(),
        'src' => array()
    )
);

listing each attribute you specifically want to allow (I took mine from the example here).
